# One to Many relation in jpa, always null in foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have some problem with relations in hibernate jpa. I'd like to make OneToMany relation but when i save object "one" in base then in table "many" column contains foreign key is always null.
In my case i have class **Customer**:

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Address billingAddress;
@Column(name="phone_address")
private String phoneNumber;
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="customer")
private List<Order> orders;
```

It contains OneToMany relation with **Order** (which works perfect). **Order** class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="order_id")
private Long orderId;
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Cart cart;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
private Customer customer;
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="order", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private Address shippingDetail;
```

**Order** class contains **Cart** (OneToOne):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="base_id")
private Long baseId;
@Column(name="cart_id")
private String cartId;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "items_keys")
private Map<Long, CartItem> cartItems;
@Column(name="grand_total")
private BigDecimal grandTotal;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Order order;
```

Here is *addCartItem* method in **Cart** class:

```
public void addCartItem(CartItem item){
    Long productId = item.getProduct().getProductId();

    if(cartItems.containsKey(productId)){
        CartItem existingCartItem = cartItems.get(productId);
        existingCartItem.setQuantity(existingCartItem.getQuantity() + item.getQuantity());
        cartItems.put(productId, existingCartItem);
    }else{
        cartItems.put(productId, item);
        //item.setCart(this);
    }
    updateGrandTotal();
}
```

And here we are, **Cart** has to contain **CartItem** map in OneToMany relation which doesn't work. **CartItem** class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="cartItem", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
private Product product;
private int quantity;
private BigDecimal totalPrice;
@ManyToOne
private Cart cart;
```

As far as i know I need to initiate foreign key in **CartItem**, i tried to do it in *addCartItem* method but when i do so, there is StackOverflowError. Did I miss something or how to initiate **CartItem** with **Cart**?

Comment: You can look into post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114984/jpa-foreign-key-is-null-in-the-child-table

Comment: I know I need to initiate CartItem, but this line of code which already is commented causes StackOverFlowError as I wrote above.

Comment: I'm inclined to guess that there is a problem somewhere else.  In particular, a `StackOverflowError` often indicates a runaway recursion.  Nothing in what you've presented gives a clue as to why such a thing might occur.  As usual, a [mcve] demonstrating the problem would be useful and appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here: [Json (fasterxml) stackoverflow exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841666/json-fasterxml-stackoverflow-exception)

The issue was in parsing my entities in REST controller and you need to use @JsonIgnore. That is all what spend me so much time -.-